# get int value including zeros (incase if it starts with 0) from string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question regarding the converting string to intvalue. My question and issue is in case if I have string called **"001223"** I am getting **1223** as intvalue. But I want to get the **001223** as final int value. Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks for your time

Comment: It is not possible, because int values do not have leading zeros!!

Comment: @TENSRI just thing about the numbers. it is not possible.

Comment: I know one thing that it is not possible but just wanted to confirm this from you guys. I thought there may be some methods to solve my issue

Comment: My intension is I want to pass 00001 as an input instead of 1 to my device. Because based on the zeros i.e each digit value may be reflect the output

Comment: I request all of you to please correct me my question or please comment me because we don't know always we are correct. Instead of downvoting why don't you guys give some suggestion.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in value between the numbers `001223` , `1223`, `2446/2` or `1223.000`. They all refer to the *same* number.

If you want to keep leading zeroes, then you need to either keep it as a string or maintain another piece of information so it can be rebuilt later, basically the number of zeroes at the front, such as:

```
struct sNumWithLeadingZeros {
    size_t       zeroCount;
    unsigned int actualValue;
};
```

I'd probably suggest the former (keeping it as a string) since that's likely to be less effort.

Answer (score 3):

"Leading zeros" are to do with the textual representation of an integer, when stored as integer values in a computer the leading zeros do not exist.

However, if what you want to do is display the number with the same number of digits it had before being converted from text then: if the string contains *only* the digits of the number, e.g. you have `@"001223"` then you can take the `length` of this string to determine the number of digits. Later when converting the number back to string format you can use a formatted conversion, e.g. `stringWithFormat:`, and a format specifier which specifies the required number of digits. You'll need to read up on formats in the documentation, but here is an example:

```
NSString *input = @"001223";
int x = [input intValue];
int digits = (int)input.length;
NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0*d", digits, x];
```

The value of `output` will be the same as `input`. The format broken down is: `0` - leading zeros; `*` use a dynamic field with, will use the value of `digits`; `d` - `int`.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

One cannot prefix leading 0s  in int data type. But if you see 0 prefix then the number is octal not decimal. Octal value can be created by changing base. For this you can use wrapper class like Integer.

But if one wants leading 0s for displaying data then he/she can use following code

```
public class Sample
{
public static void main(final String[] argv)
{
    System.out.printf("%06d", 1223);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```